# Can you configure SharePoint online to not use anchors in urls when navigating

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, navigation, url, browser-compatibility

When I navigate through SharePoint online, almost always the url in the browser looks something like this:

https://xxxxxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/Gedeelde%20%20documenten/Forms/AllItems.aspx

What I want it to be is like this:

https://xxxxxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/Gedeelde%20%20documenten/Forms/AllItems.aspx

Is it possible for me to configure my SharePoint online environment to make this happen?

I need this because I want to make use of the referral header when clicking a link I've defined in the top link bar, that directs users to my web application. But the referral header doesn't include anything after the "#" character.

I don't know how else to start my web application from SharePoint while passing on information about where the user was located within this SharePoint environment, at the moment of starting my web application.

This only really concerns me for document libraries for the time being, in case it might make this question easier to answer.

Comment: their is one feature on the site...go to site setting > manage site feature...on this page you will see "Minimal Download Strategy", please make sure this feature is deactivitated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the Minimal Download Strategy feature. Simply go to Site Settings, Manage site features, and deactive Minimal Download Strategy and you'll get normal URLs again.

Comment: Can I disable this for an entire site-collection somehow?

Comment: It is a per site setting, so it would have to be disabled everywhere, it might be able to be disabled via CSOM, I haven't checked.